# Capturing return value from helper class c#

Tags: c#, return-value

I've spent the better part of an hour reading over linked items on Google about this topic; however, maybe it just is not sinking in. What do I need to do to capture the return value from a helper class in C#? This is the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HelperClass.Calculate(a, b);
}

public static string Calculate(string a, string b)
{
    string value = string.Empty;
    // inner code workings
    return value;
}
```

I know I'm missing something but I cannot for the life of me determine what. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: `var value = HelperClass.Calculate(...);` ?

Comment: `string result = HelperClass.Calculate(a, b);`?

Comment: Jinx, you owe me a soda.

Comment: @AlphaDelta here :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like any other function, which returns a value?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value = HelperClass.Calculate(a, b);
}

public static string Calculate(string a, string b)
{
    string value = string.Empty;
    // inner code workings
    return value;
}
```

Comment: OMG ok, mind blown, I cannot believe it literally was that simple. Thank you for sparing me from tearing all my remaining hair out!

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = HelperClass.Calculate(a, b);
```